# How can I send data as Stream from native kotlin to Flutter

Tags: flutter, native, flutter-method-channel, platform-specific, flutter-native

How can I send data as a stream from native Kotlin code to Flutter?
I have implemented Method Channel, but they send only once, but I need a stream of data.

I have tried EventChannel but I'm getting error

**"Type mismatch: inferred type is  but EventChannel.StreamHandler! was expected"**

on **object : StreamHandler()**

```
EventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, STREAM )
        .setStreamHandler(
            object : StreamHandler() {
             override fun onListen(args: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink) {
                Log.w(TAG_NAME, "Adding listener")
            }
             override fun onCancel(args: Any?) {
                Log.w(TAG_NAME, "Cancelling listener")
            }
        }
    )
```

I have also used
import java.util.logging.StreamHandler

How can I solve this in Kotlin.

**Solution :  I have used EventChannel.StreamHandler instead of StreamHandler(). Now It's working fine.**

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html

Comment: I'm getting error " Type mismatch: inferred type is `<no name provided>` but EventChannel.StreamHandler! was expected""

Comment: here you have some samples: https://medium.com/cashify-engineering/event-channel-to-listen-to-broadcast-events-from-android-43a813672896

Comment: @pskink Thanks. I have used EventChannel.StreamHandler instead of StreamHandler(). Now It's working fine.